# Checking for ruby enums from another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I have two objects, Topic and Blogs, Blogs has an enum for whether it's published or not. On my site's sidebar, I have a list of topics viewable as:

```
<% @sidebar_topics.each do |x| %>
  <hr>
  <li><%= link_to x.title, topic_path(x) %></li>
<% end %>
```

But a few of them are blank, so I threw in `@sidebar_topics = Topic.with_blogs` into the controller which removes the links to the topics with NO Blogs, but, I have some where it has Blogs that are un-published, meaning: The link exists because there are blogs, but I don't want it to, because the blogs it has are still in draft mode, and therefore un-viewable, which makes the page look like it links to an empty topic...

I'm not entirely sure what info to share, what I'm after is to only have the links(@sidebar_topics) include topics that have published blogs.

Comment: Post the code for `with_blogs` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base  
  scope :with_published_blogs, -> { joins(:blogs).where(blogs: { status: 'published' }) }
end

@sidebar_topics = Topic.with_published_blogs
```

Just using the `status: 'published'` as an example which assumes your `Blog` enum looks something like `enum status: [:published, :draft]`. Fill that bit in with your own actual `enum` condition for published blogs.

Comment: dang, adding a scope... now I feel dumb, but thanks!